# How to process json data getting from multi curl?

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I have a script, which takes an ID from a database into an array and opens an url with that ID to get and process a json string.

```
$result = mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT app FROM appstoimport LIMIT 30 ") or die(mysqli_error());
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $appID = $row['app'];


//Call search 
            $cas = curl_init('https://externalsiet.com/search?id=' . $appID . '');
                curl_setopt($cas, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    $jsondata = curl_exec($cas);
                        curl_close($cas);


//Process  search
    $arr = json_decode($jsondata,true);


    foreach($arr['results'] as $item) {
        $price  = $item['price'];
        $title = $item['title'];
        $category = $item['category'];



//Insert into database  
mysqli_query($bd, "INSERT INTO apps (price, title, category) VALUES ('$price', '$title', '$category' )") or die(mysqli_error($bd));
```

now I discovered multi curl and found a script and could attach it to my query.

```
$query = mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT app FROM appstoimport LIMIT 30 ") or die(mysqli_error());
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$nodes = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $appID = $row[0];
    $nodes[] = 'https://externalsite.com/search?id=' . $row[0] . '';
}


//print_r($nodes);


$node_count = count($nodes);

$curl_arr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();

for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $url =$nodes[$i];
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
}

do {
    curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
} while($running > 0);


for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $results = curl_multi_getcontent  ( $curl_arr[$i]  );
    echo( $i . "\n" . $results . "\n");
}
```

I get back the json data fine, but they are many strings in an array now, not just a single string per call and I can't figure out, how to process it that I can insert the values into my database, like before.

Can somebody tell me, how to split up the array again so I can add them separately in a row to my database?

Comment: I just realized, that my original script puts out the same result, so I assume, there is not much difference. Can somebody confirm that?